# Programming an atm machine

Tags: python, loops

My assignment is to create an ATM-type program. Below is my main function (not including the deposit, withdraw, and check balance functions). When I go to run this code, the program loops the pin function repeatedly, even when I enter 0 or 1234. It repeatedly instructs the user to enter their pin. I think I have all of the indentation right, but I guess I'm messing up somewhere in the code.

```
def main():
    pin_number = input("Please enter your pin number")
    stop = False

    while not is_authorized(pin_number) and stop!= True:

        if pin_number == "0":
            stop == True
        if pin_number == "1234":
            stop == False  

    if stop != True:
            while True:
                choice = display_menu()
            if choice == 1:
                deposit()
            elif choice == 2:
                withdraw()
            elif choice == 3:
                check_balance()
```

Comment: stop = True not  stop == True

Comment: You probably wanted `stop = True` instead of `stop == True` .  A single equal sign _assigns_ a value, and a double equal sign _compares_ two values.

Comment: It may be helpful to use `stop == False` instead of `stop != True` just so you don't misread something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your if statements, you should be using `=` not `==`. The first is used for assigning values to variables, like you are trying to do. The second is used to compare if two values are equal and returns a boolean (true/false).

Comment: Now for some reason my program isn't properly looping. once the user deposits money, the program will run again but still say their balance is 0. Did I mess up the main while loop?

Comment: I don't think your indentation is right in the final while loop. The way you have it indented right now, the if/elif statements are not included in the while loop.

Comment: thats just on this website but i have it properly formatted in IDLE

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
if stop != True:
```

will run the code inside the loop if the variable stop is False (the user has entered the wrong code). However, you want to run the code if stop is True.
Therefore, use this code:

```
if stop == True:
```

this will run the encased code when stop is True (user has entered correct code)

EDIT:

My apologies. The above answer regards the code **following** this code:

```
if pin_number == "1234":
    stop = False
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct. If pin = 1234, stop is set to False, so shouldn't the code run when stop is False?